# Whether the following is a Dedekind cut?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am able to verify that

$$ T= \{t \in \mathbb{Q} : t^2\lt{2} \text{ or } t\lt{0}   \} $$

is a Dedekind cut.

However i have some confusion in verifying if

$$ U= \{t \in \mathbb{Q} : t^2\le{2} \text{ or } t\lt{0} \} $$

is a Dedekind cut.

I think that the set $ U $ has no largest element in $\mathbb{Q} $. Can someone show me a proof that $U$ has no largest element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $U=T$. So since one is a cut, the other is a cut as well. It is, however, marginally more immediate that $T$ is a cut, so that one is generally preferred.

Comment: Can you please show how $U=T$ ? I have no idea to show it without using the fact that between any two rational numbers, there exists an irrational number.

Comment: @sathishT Clearly $T\subset U$. If $t\in U\setminus T$ then $t\in\Bbb Q$ and $t^2=2$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Got it. Thank you